# LoadBalancer on GKE reports unhealthy for 2/3 nodes, but they are healthy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I created a cluster in `europe-west2` with:

```
REGION=europe-west2

ZONE=$(gcloud compute zones list \
    --filter "region:($REGION)" \
    | awk '{print $1}' \
    | tail -n 1)

ZONES=$(gcloud compute zones list \
    --filter "region:($REGION)" \
    | tail -n +2 \
    | awk '{print $1}' \
    | tr '\n' ',')

MACHINE_TYPE=n1-highcpu-2

gcloud container clusters \
    create test-cluster \
    --node-locations $ZONES \
    --machine-type $MACHINE_TYPE \
    --enable-ip-alias \
    --enable-autoscaling \
    --num-nodes 1 \
    --max-nodes 1 \
    --min-nodes 1 \
    --node-version "1.10.5-gke.3" \
    --cluster-version "1.10.5-gke.3"
```

But the load balancer created reports that two nodes are unhealthy, on the nodes themselves they seem perfectly healthy. I tried destroying the two nodes, but when they came back up they were still reported unhealthy by LB. Is this normal? If not, is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. Your cluster create command specifies one node. How are you building the other 2 nodes? What kind of load balancer are you using? How did you create it? How have you configured the health checks, the backend, the front end?
A possible explanation: if you’re using an nginx ingress, this may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180990/unhealthy-nodes-for-load-balancer-when-using-nginx-ingress-controller-on-gke

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's probably exactly my problem! I didn't think it was on stackoverflow... By the way, `--node-locations $ZONES` gives more locations, which effectively creates one node in each of those zones. I didn't create the LB, I think GKE created it with the cluster... all of its configuration is default.

Comment: That is my mistake Dave, thank you for clarifying your setup. Hopefully the previous article resolves your issue, if not, post back here & we can look further into it.